# Problema com SQL (adição duplicada)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho um sistema de lances que funciona com um robo dando lances automáticos, e também com um botão onde o cliente pode dar lance.

Quando o cliente clica no botão, ele chama uma função que executa a seguinte query:

```
$qryins = "Insert into bid_account (user_id,bidpack_buy_date,bid_count,auction_id,product_id,bid_flag,bidding_price,bidding_type,bidding_time)
                values('$uid',NOW(),'1','$aid','$prid','d',$newprice,'s'," . $oldtime . ")";
```

A parte dos robos é feita por uma procedure no banco de dados, com o seguinte comando:

```
Insert into bid_account (user_id, bidpack_buy_date, bid_count, auction_id, product_id, bid_flag, bidding_price, bidding_type, bidding_time)
        SELECT prox_user_id, NOW(), '1', auctionID, productID, 'd', prox_valor, 's', auc_due_time FROM t_autolances
        WHERE prox_valor NOT IN (SELECT bidding_price FROM bid_account WHERE auction_id=auctionID);
```

Os lances são executados com um relógio, tipo aqueles leilões de centavos. O problema que esta ocorrendo é que se o cliente clicar no botão no mesmo tempo que o robo der o lance, ele grava no banco de dados com os mesmos valores.

Por exemplo cronometro ta em 2s, nesse tempo o robo vai da o lance e o cliente também deu. Verificando a tabela bid_account é possível ver que os valores ficaram duplicados, todos com as mesmas informações.

Como posso fazer para que ele grave um de cada vez? Na verdade o que preciso é que ele grave o valor diferente somente para a coluna **bidding_price**, pois esta possuí os valores como por exemplo: 0.25

Preciso que seja gravado dessa forma:

```
robo 0.25
cliente 0.26
```

e não assim:

```
robo 0.25
cliente 0.25
```

Eu não quis colocar todo o código aqui por que é muito extenso, então coloquei as partes mais importantes.

Comment: Desculpe perguntar mas o robô existe para inflacionar os lances ?

Comment: @Motta o robo existe para atingir o preço minimo de um produto.

Comment: ok , no caso eu também estudaria um "lock table" https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables-and-triggers.html

Comment: Como seria? Se puder me dar algum exemplo com as mesma query, por que não tenho conhecimento nessa parte.

Comment: Não conheço MySql a ponto de fazer a síntaxe , apenas de um conceito de Banco de Dados.

Answer (score 0):

A melhor solução seria utilizar o last_id_inserted e depois utilizar esse id para fazer uma query com as relações existentes.

```
   $query =" Insert into bid_account (user_id, bidpack_buy_date, bid_count, auction_id, product_id, bid_flag, bidding_price, bidding_type, bidding_time)";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

if($result){

 $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);

$query_two =" SELECT prox_user_id, NOW(), '1', auctionID, productID, 'd', prox_valor, 's', auc_due_time FROM t_autolances
        WHERE prox_valor NOT IN (SELECT bidding_price FROM bid_account WHERE id='$last_id')"; 

}
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, isso iria funcionar? Pois eles iriam ser executados exatamente ao mesmo tempo, não tem como verificar um antes.

Comment: Lembrando que cada query é separada uma da outra, uma fica em uma procedure no banco de dados e a outra em um arquivo PHP.

Comment: Que tal fazeres assim, fazes que o robo ou o cliente um deles tenha prioridade na bid, desta forma ele vai selecionar um vencedor, e o concorrente fica pendente. Crias um array com pitch e um array para vencedor e comparas as bids através do valor que este insere, tempo e também o tipo de user, se é robo ou cliente.

Comment: O vencedor só é selecionado quando o cronômetro zerar, e isso não pode acontecer sem contabilizar os dois lances, no caso do robô e do cliente.

Comment: Já dei a resposta ao seu problema.